# Why my Wordpress is trying to connect to an strange url?

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I'm managing a Wordpress site and in the lasts months an strange 502 Bad Gateway error has been appearing. I enabled the log and discovered that it tries to access to strange urls like:

- gd-join.com
- www.toupiaovip.com
- balkanskichat.com
- gtaturk.com

The log line is this:

> stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://gtaturk.com:80
>   (Connection timed out) in
>   /usr/share/nginx/html/wp-includes/class-http.php on line 1008

What could be the reason?

Comment: Your site could be compromised via a vulnerable Wordpress extension.